# Can I get the texts in a word document from a vsto add-in?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

This may sound silly, but I want to be able to filter out the texts from a word document using just its path without opening the file. I have searched through the internet and have come across a tool called `IFilter` which seem to sound like what I need. I have tried to find out how it can be used in vsto projects but couldn't get any useful information. Is it possible to get text from a file using `IFilter`in vsto add-in, is there a different package that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Look at Open XML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-open-a-word-processing-document-for-read-only-access

Comment: @Boeryepes, thanks a bunch for your comment. Yes that is exactly what I want. Thanks again.